# Parse Error : Syntax Error

Tags: php, html, text

I'm getting a parse error, can anyone please advise what I'm missing:

Error on browser is :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Content' (T_STRING) in /path/coder.php on line 8

Line 8 is :

```
$stringData = "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">;\n";
```

Comment: @rizier123 

I think it is because of the double quotes that i have in the line.. but i need them as part of the html code.. 



so not sure how to add the complete line 

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: Yes! It's because of the double quotes. Now you have 2 options to solve this where some are more elegant than the others. 1. Change the inner double quotes to single quotes e.g. `$stringData = "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>;\n";` 2. Escape the inner double quotes e.g. `$stringData = "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">;\n";`

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks for that nugget of knowledge.. I have tested that and used both suggestions, and it has worked a treat.. 

Many Thanks Again.